# How to Split a string using the delimiter with quotes and white spaces?

Tags: c#, linq, split

I want to split a string using only the delimiter. But my code is breaking if the string has white spaces.

```
1233;"Order";Placed at 10 AM;1
```

When I split it, the out put is

```
1233
\"Order"\
Placed 
at
10
AM
1
```

Expected output is:

```
1233
\"Order"\
Placed at 10 AM
1
```

My Code:

```
                    var result = columns[0].Split(';')
                 .Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0  
                  ? element.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None)                                             : new string[] { element })  // Keep the entire item
                 .SelectMany(element => element).ToList();
```

Thanks for fixing this issue.

Comment: do you want to encapsulate words that are in quotes in extra backslashes? like this: `\"Order"\`?

Answer (score 3):

Just keep only the first line.

```
var result = columns[0].Split(';');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitely also splitting on spaces: `Split(new[] { ' ' }`.

If you only want to split on semicolons, this is sufficient:

```
var result = columns[0].Split(';');
```

You might also consider using a library like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).